# Document image dewarping script on Python 3.5

Tags: python, python-2to3

I'm trying to run the following script on windows: https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp.

It requires `scipy`, `numpy`, `pillow` and OpenCV.

I have no experience with python, I have downloaded `WinPython` (http://winpython.github.io/), which includes `scipy`, `numpy` and `pillow` and also installed OpenCV 3.2 for Python 3.5 following the instructions found here: https://pythonarena.wordpress.com/2016/03/07/scientific-python-on-windows/.

Now I'm trying to run the script using the command `page_dewarp.py IMAGE1`, as indicated by the developer, but it results in a syntax error.

Could you explain if there is something missing or wrong and, eventually, how to do to make it work properly?

Thank you!

Comment: I have been trying to get this script to work too. I think there are some other changes that occurred in the modules he imports during the transition from python 2 to 3. I can't quite be sure but I think it might be in the way division changed and that's effecting the way his bumpy arrays work. Once I figure out more I'll try to get back to you

Answer (score 3):

[`page_dewarp.py`](https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp/blob/master/page_dewarp.py) contains [`print` statements](https://github.com/mzucker/page_dewarp/blob/master/page_dewarp.py#L739), so it will not work with Python 3.

Comment: With Python 2.7 it gives the following error: ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WinPython27\pagedewarp\page_dewarp.py", line 15, in <module>
    import cv2
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

Answer (score 1):

Try putting braces around the content of print statements as:

```
print 'abc'
```

to

```
print('abc')
```

This should solve the syntax problem. You might need to install scipy. This can be done using

```
pip install scipy
```

Answer (score 0):

After cloning the repo, Just checkout 'support-python3' branch. It supports the python3 and OpenCV4.

```
git checkout support-python3
```

Answer (score -1):

`page_dewarp.py` is in python2.
You just need to convert it into python3.
Just copy all content of that file and convert it into python3 code by using [this](https://www.pythonconverter.com/) website. And then replace the content of that file with converted code.

Comment: Converted to python 3 using a similar website and the parentheses problem is gone but I still can't seem to get it working.

I get this  : 

page_dewarp.py [IMAGE1.jpg]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    page_dewarp.py [IMAGE1.jpg]
NameError: name 'page_dewarp' is not defined

I did put an IMAGE1.jpg in the same folder as the .py file but cannot get it working.